# XPages and .svg files

Tags: image, svg, xpages

I've added an image in .svg format to my file resources, but it seems I can't use it with the xpages image control nor the img tag.

Is there something I need to do first or does XPages not support the usage of .svg files?

Any help / answer would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In File resources, select the file, go to web properties and type in the Mime type as `image/svg+xml`.

Since Domino does not recognise SVG file type, it cannot suggest a mime type for the response.

[image: Setting MIME Type]

Comment: Serdar, thank you very much for your response. You've made my day, that worked!!

Comment: if you display this "file" in an IMG tag the browser would treat it as an image so you wouldn't get any performance gains compared to a normal img